# Is there a content Header Type for adding HttpResponseHeader?

Tags: c#, .net, http-response-codes

The only method I see in HttpResponseHeaders is Add which takes string type for header type.
I just wonder did .NET provided a list of HttpResponseHeader type contants in string?

So I can do:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse.........;
response.Headers.Add(xxxxx.ContentRange, "something");
```

I can see there is a list of Enum in HttpResponseHeader, but it doesn't provide string value conrespondingly...

i.e HttpResponseHeader.ContentRange, but the correct header string should be Content-Range

Correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three strongly-typed HTTP header classes in the System.Net.Http.Headers namespace:

- [HttpContentHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.aspx)
- [HttpRequestHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.aspx)
- [HttpResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders.aspx)

HttpContentHeaders (which is accessible via the `Headers` property of any of the System.Net.Http.HttpContent types) has pre-defined properties for *Content-Type*, *Content-Length*, *Content-Encoding* etc... (which seem to be the headers you were after).

You can set them like this:

```
var content = new StringContent("foo");
content.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/plain";
```

...and the header names will be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this.

```
var whc = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection();
whc.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.ContentRange, "myvalue");
Response.Headers.Add(whc);
```

In a webapi context, the last line could be :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add(whc);
```

anyway, @ServiceGuy's answer is the way to go in a webapi/mvc context

Hope this will help

Comment: The HttpResponseHeaders.Add only accept (string,string) and (string,IEnumerable<string>)... Deosn't accept WebHeaderCollection itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set common headers by property on WebRequest and WebResponse, like [HttpWebRequest.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

C# has a built-in conversion from Enum to string. Consider these assignments:

```cs
int val = 5;
HttpResponseHeader header = HttpResponseHeader.Allow
```

Now, `val.ToString()` will return the string `"5"`, but `header.ToString()` will return `"Allow"`. So I humbly suggest using

```cs
response.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.ContentRange.ToString(), "something");
```

Comment: enum ContentRange to string is going to be "ContentRange" as well, but the correct Header is "Content-Range", that's what I was stated in the question.

Comment: Hmm. Is the header correctly formatted anyways? (looking at the request in something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: It looks like there's come special considerations for Range and Content-Range headers. [Here's some reading material](http://www.piotrwalat.net/file-download-service-with-resume-support-using-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ContentType Property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx.

I was able to do this in my WCF service implementation by doing the following:

```
// Get the outgoing response portion of the current context
var response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

// Add ContentType header that specifies we are using JSON
response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json").ToString();
```